# How to find in string all matches

Tags: c#, regex

Assume that I have the following string:

> xx##a#11##yyy##bb#2##z

Im trying to retrieve all occurrence of `##something#somethingElse##`

(In my string I want to have 2 matches: `##a#11##` and `##bb#2##`)

I tried to get all matches using

```
Regex.Matches(MyString, ".*(##.*#.*##).*")
```

but it retrieves one match which is the whole row.

How can I get all matches from this string? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have `.*` at the start and end of your pattern, you only get the whole line match. Besides, `.*` in-between `#`s in your pattern is too greedy, and would grab all the expected matches into 1 match when encountered on a single line.

You may use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(MyString, "##[^#]*#[^#]*##")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23%23%5B%5E%23%5D*%23%5B%5E%23%5D*%23%23&i=xx%23%23a%2311%23%23yyy%23%23bb%232%23%23z)

**NOTE**: If there must be at least 1 char in between `##` and `#`, and `#` and `##`, replace `*` quantifier (matching 0+ occurrences) with `+` quantifier (matching 1+ occurrences).

**NOTE2:** To avoid matches inside `####..#....#####`, you may add lookarounds: `"(?<!#)##[^#]+#[^#]+##(?!#)"`

**Pattern details**:

- `##` - 2 `#` symbols
- `[^#]*` / `[^#]+`  - a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching 0+ chars (or 1+ chars) other than `#`
- `#` - a single `#`
- `[^#]*` / `[^#]+` -  0+ (or 1+) chars other than `#`
- `##` - double `#` symbol.

BONUS: To get the contents inside `##` and `##`, use a *capturing group*, a pair of unescaped `(...)` around the part of the pattern you need to extract, and grab `Match.Groups[1].Value`s:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(MyString, @"##([^#]*#[^#]*)##")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: the issue with * is that it will match `#####`

Comment: @abc123: It all depends on the requirements, the `*` can be replaced with `+` then. I added more tweaking options as **NOTES**.

Comment: Thanks :)
According to your help, I also manged to get the matches without the enclosing ##  (i.e. get a#1 instead of ##a#1##).

I used this pattern: [^##][^#]*#[^#]*[^##]

Comment: But  then you'd use   a capturing group, let me show.

Answer (score 4):

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Nt8IrG/1)

`Regex.Matches(MyString, "(##[^#]+#[^#]+##)")`

---

```
(##[^#]+#[^#]+##)
```

Description

```
1st Capturing Group (##[^#]+#[^#]+##)
    ## matches the characters ## literally (case sensitive)
    Match a single character not present in the list below [^#]+
        + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    # matches the character # literally (case sensitive)
    # matches the character # literally (case sensitive)
    Match a single character not present in the list below [^#]+
        + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    # matches the character # literally (case sensitive)
    ## matches the characters ## literally (case sensitive)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/BZ6VMysLPmQf-BgC)